# Deployed Wordpress on Bluemix.net using a Boilerplate - Now I can't figure out how to add a new plugin

Tags: wordpress, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I learned the hard way that plugins can and will disappear if I add them via the UI. According to the help: "Bluemix, like other cloud platforms, has an ephemeral filesystem. Every time you push or restart your app, the container that stores the files for your app is destroyed and recreated. If you update the WordPress Core from the UI, then the update is rolled back when your app is restarted."

So I'm now trying to add them via the Cloud Foundry command line interface as suggested in the help docs.

I downloaded the application starter code, extracted it to a New_folder, downloaded the plugin I wanted, extracted that to the New_folder/wp-content/plugins/ and then tried to do a cf push. I got no errors but the plugin is not showing up in the wp-admin page.

Total Wordpress newbie here... Can anyone provide me any clues on what I'm doing wrong or steps I'm missing? Has anyone else tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it working. I figured it out with help from the Bluemix dev team, here is what they said:

We are still waiting for our updated documentation to land. We should have synchronized the updated deployment with the corresponding documentation updates, sorry for the trouble.

Until the docs at https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/wordpress/index.html#wordpress are updated, please follow the steps posted at https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/181148/wordpress-changed-wordpress-file-not-uploaded/#answer-181784 and report back if you have any trouble.